# Cannot use ContractAbbreviator in ContractClass?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I've just started using [code-contracts](/questions/tagged/code-contracts) and found that the [ContractAbbreviator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contractabbreviatorattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute makes it possible to describe contracts in a clean way.

However, I'm not able to make it work in a contract class for an abstract class.

Given this simple class:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(MyContractClass))]
internal abstract class MyClass
{
    public abstract int Position { get; }

    public abstract void Reset();
}
```

I'd like to write a contract class that ensures that:

- `Position` is always greater than or equal to zero.
- `Position` is zero for newly created instances.
- `Reset()` causes `Position` to revert to it's initial value (zero).

So, I came up with this contract class:

```
[ContractClassFor(typeof(MyClass))]
internal abstract class MyContractClass : MyClass
{
    internal MyContractClass()
    {
        this.EnsuresInitialState();
    }

    public override int Position
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= 0);
            return default(int);
        }
    }

    public override void Reset()
    {
        this.EnsuresInitialState();
    }

    [ContractAbbreviator]
    private void EnsuresInitialState()
    {
        Contract.Ensures(this.Position == 0);
    }
}
```

However, when compiling this I get the following error:

> Contract class `MyContractClass` references member `MyContractClass.EnsuresInitialState` which is not part of the abstract class/interface being annotated.

**Does that mean that it's impossible to use [ContractAbbreviator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contractabbreviatorattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) methods in a contract class, or am I doing something wrong here?**

*In this simple class there is really no point in having an abbreviator, since the state to ensure is just a single property. In my real class, however, there are several other properties that I want to ensure are reverted back to their initial values.*

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the constructor contract?  Since the abstract class has a non-abstract constructor, you probably ought to define the constructor contract in the abstract class itself.  Then you can possibly make the abbreviation method protected, and call it also from the contract class.

Comment: @phoog That's clever, and it works like a charm! However, it generated code analysis warning CA2214: Do not call overridable methods in constructor. I guess the contract is validated before the constructor of deriving classes are called. Making it useless? Maybe the solution is to have the abbreviation in the base class and make sure derived classes call it from their constructors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `EnsuresInitialState` method to the abstract class and mark it protected. Then add a default constructor to the abstract class that calls it:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(MyContractClass))]
internal abstract class MyClass
{
    protected MyClass()
    {
        EnsuresInitialState();
    }

    [ContractAbbreviator]
    protected void EnsuresInitialState()
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Position == 0);
    }

    public abstract int Position { get; }

    public abstract void Reset();
}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(MyClass))]
internal abstract class MyContractClass : MyClass
{
    public override int Position
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= 0);
            return default(int);
        }
    }

    public override void Reset()
    {
        EnsuresInitialState();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just notice that calling a virtual/abstract method from the constructor (like `get_Position` here) is generally a bad idea since you might read uninitialized data from a derived class.